# How can I automatically rescale the y axis of my log chart using ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Here is an example of one run of my chart:

[image]

**Chart configuration:**

At the moment I just set a maximum tick value, i.e. `max: 100000000`. I figure I need to pass some function that adjusts the maximum value whenever the largest exceeds the largest value of the y axis. How can this be done?

```
_chart.chart_3.config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Harvest 1', 'Harvest 2', 'Harvest 3', 'Harvest 4','Harvest 5'],
        datasets: [{
            lineTension: 0,
            label: 'Bill',
            data: [],
            fill: false,
            fillColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
            borderColor: "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
        },
        {
            lineTension: 0,
            label: 'Ann',
            data: [],
            fill: false,
            fillColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        },
        {
            lineTension: 0,
            label: 'Bill (Sharing)',
            data: [],
            fill: false,
            fillColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(4, 0, 255)",
            borderColor: "rgb(4, 0, 255)",
        },
        {
            lineTension: 0,
            label: 'Ann (Sharing)',
            data: [],
            fill: false,
            fillColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
            borderColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
        },
        {
            lineTension: 0,
            label: 'Pool',
            data: [],
            fill: false,
            fillColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(128,36,171)",
            borderColor: "rgb(128,36,171)",
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: ''
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false,
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'KG',
                },
                type: 'logarithmic',
                position: 'left',
                ticks: {
                     min: 0, //minimum tick
                     max: newMax(value), //maximum tick
                     callback: function (value, index, values) {
                         return Number(value.toString()); //pass tick values as a string into Number function
                     }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

**New max function:**

```
newMax = function(values) {
    max = Math.max(values)
    max = max * 1.2
    return Number(max.toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but I'm assuming it's an array of values with numbers, all you'd need to do is find the max number than add a little buffer on the end to keep the graph looking pretty, so the max number it goes to, then add a little on the end.

```
function getMax(arr) {
  const max = Math.max(...arr).toString();
  const newMax = 1 + "0".repeat(max.length);
  return newMax
}
```

```
max: getMax(values)
```

Comment: Say the current value is 94. Once it reaches 100, I want the next bar on the y axis to show 1000. Once it reaches 1000, it should show 10,000 and so on, step-wise, for every power of 10.

Comment: Should be `Math.ceil(max / 10) * 100`  which would turn 99 to 1000, 999 to 10000 etc.

Comment: If I knew how to get the current array in ``max:`` I may be able to update it with ``max: Math.ceil((Math.max(values)) / 10) * 100``, but I'm not sure how to do that. in ChartJS. ``values`` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have come to realize I am very bad at math.
`const max = Math.max(...arr).toString();`
`const newMax = 1 + "0".repeat(max.length);` 
This should just round down and add a 0 to the end every time you go up a bracket, so anything between 1001-9999  is 10000

What you're trying to do should work with `(...values)` not `(values)`

Comment: What is `values` or `value`? it should work fine though, maybe you can simplify it by just making a function return the max, so you don't have to in-line it or anything.

I updated the answer with an example

Comment: I've tried something like that but I'm not sure how to retrieve the maximum value from multiple time series. I posted an issue (and my attempt with your code) on the official git repo: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/6205